# How to add event handlers to child components of SortableElement?

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I've just used the `react-sortable-hoc` library.

But I'm having trouble handling events which have been bound to the elements that are inside of SortableElement. Before adding the "sort" feature, event handlers were working fine. But now, they have become unresponsive, it seems that control does not reach the event handlers.

The following is the code of SortableElement:

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ image, editCaption, classes, dispatch, handleChangeCaption, handleImageDelete, handleSaveCaptionClick, handleEditCaptionClick }) => (
<TableRow key={image.id}>
    <TableCell className={classes.imageCell}>
        <img src={image.src}
            onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "OPEN_LIGHT_BOX", imageUrl: image.src })}
            className={classes.image}
        />
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell className={classes.captionCell}>
        <div className={editCaption.indexOf(image.id) !== -1 ? "" : classes.imageCaption}>
            {
                editCaption.indexOf(image.id) !== -1
                    ?
                    <textarea
                        value={image.caption}
                        className={classes.inputImageCaption}
                        onChange={handleChangeCaption(image.id)}
                    />
                    :
                    image.caption
            }
        </div>
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell className={classes.actionCell}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faTrashAlt}
            className={classes.deleteIcon}
            title={"Remove image"}
            onClick={handleImageDelete(image.id)}
        />
        {
            editCaption.indexOf(image.id) !== -1
                ?
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faSave}
                    className={classes.editImageCaption}
                    title={"Save changes"}
                    onClick={handleSaveCaptionClick(image.id)}
                />
                :
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faPencilAlt}
                    className={classes.editImageCaption}
                    title={"Edit caption"}
                    onClick={handleEditCaptionClick(image.id)}
                />
        }

    </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

));

> As you can see there a number of event handlers have been added:
>       -> **onClick** on **img**
>       -> **onClick** on **FontAwesomeIcon**

Can anyone please point out what I should do to make child events work?

Comment: this seems to be documented: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc#click-events-being-swallowed

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I did refer to the Click events being swallowed section. But the solutions that were presented there did not work for me. I used pressDelay, distance props on SortableContainer and even SortableHandler in place of SortableElement but in all cases the event fired but the sorting stopped. I finally resorted to using the shouldCancelStart prop. I return true from it if the event was fired from a component that had an event handler assigned to it. And it works like I want it to work. If you have a better solution, let me know.